# Promise on older versions of javascript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, promise

I am currently working with typescript and the new ECMAscript 6 feature Promise. My question is, can I use the Promise feature if my TypeScript gets compiled to a f.e. ECMAscript 3 js-file? I mean the Promise wasn't implemented at this version.

Comment: Get any of the many ES6-compatible promise libraries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a polyfill:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-promise-polyfill

To install:

```
bower install es6-promise-polyfill
```

To use:

```
<script src="bower_components/es6-promise-polyfill/promise.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var promise = new Promise(...);
</script>
```

Comment: if this is working, can you indicate that by selecting it as the correct answer?